# How to create a RAM Drive (RAM Disk) in Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: performance, windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, memory, ramdisk

There are lots of tools for creating RAM drives. None of them seem to work for windows 2008 R2. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how. Does anyone know of a tool that does work?

I've tried the gavotte ram disk. It doesn't work. When i try to install it it just sais "Failed". I don't see log files anywhere. I've tried a couple of other ones (forgot the names) to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've got an old version of the [StarWind iSCSI Target](http://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind) software that works in 2008 R2 and can create RAM disks. It's not free, and it comes with an iSCSI wrapper, but it still works.

Answer (score 4):

[ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) is a virtual disk driver for Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista/7/8 or Windows Server 2003/2008/2012

http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk

Current version 1.8.0 built 01 May 2014

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia seems to have a pretty complete list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software#Microsoft_Windows

There are a lot of others in addition to ImDisk and StarWind.